# Add identifier to browser bookmarks

Tags: url, google-analytics, bookmarks

Is there a way to automatically append an identifier to a page URL when it is bookmarked in the browser, perhaps something in the document head that gives the browser a directive or an onBookmark JavaScript type of event? I'm looking for ways to further segment my direct traffic in Google Analytics (if you have other ideas for doing that not related to bookmarks, please share them as well).

**Example**:

```
http://www.example.com/article
```

When bookmarked becomes:

```
http://www.example.com/article#bookmarked
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can reliably do what you're describing. The best you could do is have a button on your pages that uses window.external.AddFavorite, and then specify your hashed address. It will work for the people who use the button, which may be better than nothing.

Comment: +1, but I have to add: I doubt that this may be better than nothing. Currently, he has one question: how many visitors by bookmark. With that solution, he'll have yet another question soon.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, though certainly easy enough to implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that *bookmark* traffic is not simply part of your direct traffic.
There is a nice demonstration in Justin Cutroni's blog how [Google Analytics tracks *bookmark* visits](http://www.epikone.com/blog/2009/05/20/how-google-analytics-tracks-bookmark-visits/) and it turned out, that most of the time, *bookmark* visits are shown as organic (if you suppose, that people first do a Google search and then bookmark your site).

Comment: Very interesting link and a piece of information that I didn't know before. Unfortunately, it now makes me question almost ALL of my analytics information. :P